# Linux "rpl" command doesn't replace text

Tags: grep

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Linux “rpl” command doesn't replace text](https://superuser.com/questions/351663/linux-rpl-command-doesnt-replace-text)

I'm using `rpl` program in linux to replace `date(` with `pdate(` in some files.
But it says `A Total of 0 matches replaced in 1 file searched.`
while grep output for `date(` is:

```
ariyan@ariyan-laptop:/var/www/moodle21$ grep -wR 'date(' admin/uploaduser.php
$today = make_timestamp(date('Y', $today), date('m', $today), date('d', $today), 0, 0, 0);
```

I'm using `rpl` as this:

```
rpl -wR 'date(' 'pdate(' admin/uploaduser.php
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Why `rpl` and not `sed`?

Comment: Also cross post: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23512/linux-rpl-command-doesnt-replace-text

Comment: @enzotib: Hi,and thanks for response; because there are lots of file that I want to replace texts in them at once. I don't know that `sed` can do this on multiple files or not.

Comment: Yes, it can, alone or in combination with `find`, or with some bash scripting.

Comment: @enzotib: I did it using `find . -iname '*.php' -exec sed -i 's/\bdate\b/pdate/g' '{}' \;` .thanks

Comment: @enzotib: `find . -exec sed -i 's/\bdate\b/pdate/g' {} \;` will be enough - there is no known shell, where you need to mask {}. :)

Comment: ... and it is already anwered on SU. I flagged it as CP.